# Accessing folder inside WordPress installed website cpanel

Tags: wordpress, ftp, hosting

I have website in which there is word press installed,now i just crated ftp account to certain directory say www.certainwebsite.com/username
now when  i goto this link,it keeps me tracked back to www.certainwebsite.com isntead of goign to this link of www.certainwebsite.com/username .
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only serving static files out of that folder, try dropping an .htaccess file in the subdirectory that turns off the rewrite engine.

Create a text file called .htaccess in that directory with something like this in it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where to find .htacess file ?

Comment: you'll need to create one. You could also potentially change the root .htaccess for your site to allow the subdirectory to bypass the rewrite, but I think that's more likely to break down the road.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

See my edit above for example.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to change http:// to ftp://

Comment: this isn't really specific enough and probably doesn't answer the question. The host may not be using FTP at all.

Comment: It asks for username and password and then ,not found error comes up.